# Build Java project with waf

Tags: java, python, jar, wsh, waf

I have used [this](https://github.com/hwaf/waf/blob/master/demos/java/wscript) demo code to create a wscript that builds my java project. Now I want a jar file to be created in a different output directory than the one my class files are created in.

When I try to add this line:

```
jaropts = '-C default/src/ .', # can be used to give files
```

python says:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Is it even possible to specify multiple output paths for individual files with waf and is jaropts the right place to configure that?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/java_test/.waf-1.8.10-f3a5181891ad6643633329fcfb4381b3/waflib/Scripting.py", line 108, in waf_entry_point
    run_commands()
  File "/home/user/java_test/.waf-1.8.10-f3a5181891ad6643633329fcfb4381b3/waflib/Scripting.py", line 169, in run_commands
    ctx=run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/home/user/java_test/.waf-1.8.10-f3a5181891ad6643633329fcfb4381b3/waflib/Scripting.py", line 160, in run_command
    ctx.execute()
  File "/home/user/java_test/.waf-1.8.10-f3a5181891ad6643633329fcfb4381b3/waflib/Scripting.py", line 371, in execute
    return execute_method(self)
  File "/home/user/java_test/.waf-1.8.10-f3a5181891ad6643633329fcfb4381b3/waflib/Build.py", line 104, in execute
    self.execute_build()
  File "/home/user/java_test/.waf-1.8.10-f3a5181891ad6643633329fcfb4381b3/waflib/Build.py", line 111, in execute_build
    self.compile()
  File "/home/user/java_test/.waf-1.8.10-f3a5181891ad6643633329fcfb4381b3/waflib/Build.py", line 174, in compile
    self.producer.start()
  File "/home/user/java_test/.waf-1.8.10-f3a5181891ad6643633329fcfb4381b3/waflib/Runner.py", line 170, in start
    self.refill_task_list()
  File "/home/user/java_test/.waf-1.8.10-f3a5181891ad6643633329fcfb4381b3/waflib/Runner.py", line 98, in refill_task_list
    self.outstanding.extend(self.biter.next())
  File "/home/user/java_test/.waf-1.8.10-f3a5181891ad6643633329fcfb4381b3/waflib/Build.py", line 405, in get_build_iterator
    self.post_group()
  File "/home/user/java_test/.waf-1.8.10-f3a5181891ad6643633329fcfb4381b3/waflib/Build.py", line 389, in post_group
    f()
  File "/home/user/java_test/.waf-1.8.10-f3a5181891ad6643633329fcfb4381b3/waflib/TaskGen.py", line 110, in post
    v()
  File "/home/user/java_test/.waf-1.8.10-f3a5181891ad6643633329fcfb4381b3/waflib/Tools/javaw.py", line 122, in jar_files
    jaropts.append('-C')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at [the source](https://github.com/waf-project/waf/blob/master/waflib/Tools/javaw.py), `jaropts` should be an argument list, not a string.

Try `jaropts = ['-C', 'default/src/', '.']`